# AWS Boto3 Security Groups management

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-security-group

I wish to find which security groups refers only to another security group and not to EC2 instance (for example).
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_security_group_references is only for VPCs.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information as to WHY you want this? We might be able to suggest a better way to achieve your goal. For example, is it to figure out the impact of changes to security groups?

Comment: I wish to eliminate SG that are referenced only by another SG.

Comment: discussed with AWS team. there's now direct nor easy way to do such thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `describe_security_group_references` is supported only for VPC and only for groups involved in a peering connection.  This is not a limitation of boto3 but, rather, of the EC2 API.

To get the equivalent functionality for non-VPC security groups you would have to retrieve all of those groups via `describe_security_groups` and then write your own code to find the groups which only reference other groups.